Can anchor client be used with @solana/web3.js 2.0rc?
Anza team introduced new version of solana web3.js.
It has significant changes in its structure.
Can I use web3.js 2.0 with anchor client to interact with solana program?
For example:
import { IdlAccounts, Program, getProvider } from "@coral-xyz/anchor";
import { clusterApiUrl, Connection, PublicKey } from "@solana/web3.js";
export const program = new Program<AAA>(IDL, {
  connection
});

export const [gamePdaAccount] = PublicKey.findProgramAddressSync(
  [Buffer.from(gamePDASeed)],
  program.programId
);

export type GamePdaAccount = IdlAccounts<AAA>["gamePdaAccount"];

This is my previous code before web3.js 2.0
Can this be still used or how to migrate into new web3.js 2.0?
Is there corresponding anchor client to web3.js 2.0?

New web3.js doesn't use PublicKey. Instead, its use Address. After simply changing it, it will work well?

Currently, the Anchor TS library does not support web3.js 2.0. The entire Anchor client is strictly dependent on web3.js version 1.x.
I recommend following this issue for updates on the functionality, though it doesn’t seem like it will be implemented soon:
https://github.com/coral-xyz/anchor/issues/3243

I think using kinobi is a good method just now.

With the release of @solana/web3.js version 2, we’ve introduced a tool for generating program clients using Codama IDLs (formerly Kinobi), fully compatible with this version.
You can convert your Anchor IDL to a Codama IDL using the @codama/nodes-from-anchor package which you can then use to generate clients in various languages using @codama/renderers.
There will be a CLI to tackle all this in the future, but for now, you can follow these simple steps.
First, install Codama, its Anchor adapter and its renderers.
pnpm install codama @codama/nodes-from-anchor @codama/renderers

Then, write a small script that, given an Anchor IDL, generates JavaScript code compatible with the new web3.js.
import { createFromRoot } from 'codama';
import { rootNodeFromAnchor } from '@codama/nodes-from-anchor';
import { renderJavaScriptVisitor } from '@codama/renderers';

// Instanciate Codama.
const idlPath = path.join('path', 'to', 'idl.json');
const idl = require(idl);
const codama = createFromRoot(rootNodeFromAnchor(idl));

// Render JavaScript.
const generatedPath = path.join('path', 'to', 'js-client', 'src');
codama.accept(renderJavaScriptVisitor(generatedPath));

After running this script, you should see a variety of helper types and functions for all accounts and instructions available in your program. You can now use this JS client in your apps or publish it on NPM for other devs to use.
Note that we are currently doing the latter with core Solana programs.
